# Case statement changes the resulting data type of my view

Tags: sql, oracle11g, case

We made a change to a view last night that our overnight ETL process looks at.
Instead of simply showing a column with a data type of `NUMBER(38)`, we made it to a case statement similar to the below:

```
CASE
  WHEN WEB_SALES.WIDX IS NOT NULL THEN WEB_SALES.WIDX
  WHEN TRANH.MAILORDER = 1 THEN TRANH.WIDX
  ELSE NULL
END
```

The data type of the view changed from a `NUMBER(38)` to just a `NUMBER` which made SSIS complain about incorrect meta data.

My question is, if both of the fields referenced in the case statement have the data type of `NUMBER(38)`, why was the resulting data type of the view `NUMBER`?

It appears to be the `ELSE NULL` that is causing it to change- if I put one of the `NUMBER(38)` fields in the `ELSE`, then the resulting data type is `NUMBER(38)`.... so why does the `ELSE NULL` cause the view to loose the precision on the data type?

Comment: I don't know about why it does it, but you could try making the `else` part `cast(null number(38))` instead of just `null`

Comment: Since null means unknown, Oracle is probably doing the safest thing. _The absence of precision and scale designators specifies the maximum range and precision for an Oracle number._

Comment: @JRD- that sounds like a logical explanation. One of the gotchas I'll have to remember.

Comment: If what Sentinel is suggesting not working, may be you can try cast the whole case statement to number(38)